# How to refresh a list of checkboxes dynamically in Angular 6.0

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a modal that displays a list of check boxes based on what drop a user selects on that modal. My issue is getting the list to refresh.
Here is my code:

modals.components.html

```
           <label for="channel">Channel</label>
           <select formControlName="channel" (change)="loadNewProducts($event)">
                 <option [value]="channel" *ngFor="let channel of channels">{{channel}}</option>
           </select>  

           <div style="float: left;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px;" *ngFor="let product of myForm.controls['myproducts'].controls; let i = index">
                 <input type="checkbox" [formControl]="product">
               <label style="padding-left: 5px;">{{ products[i].name }}</label>
           </div>
```

There is two arrays - one has the products and the other array has a true/false if its been selected. When I select a item in channels - I call a "loadNewProducts" with a value. Then I need it to reload my "products"

In my modals.component.ts
I have declared a few empty arrays:

> products=[];   products_selected=[];

here is my loadNewProducts

```
    loadNewProducts (event: any) {
      //update the ui
      console.log("product",event.target.value);
      this.products=this.another_list;
      this.myForm.controls['myproducts']=this.another_list;
    }
```

This is where I'm failing. I'm trying to update the product list with new list and not sure how to do it. Any ideas (is this clear)?

Comment: Did you console the this.products? Does it change when you click on a dropdown option?

Comment: Yes I did. I just verified that my array is changing dynamically. Just the gui not updating. Most likely cause I'm doing something wrong.